# unique iid when generating treeview with for loop

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I'm trying to generate a treeview with a for loop to display a bunch of data. Now I could easily generate a treeview without naming the iid and doing something like tree.insert(), however, I'm trying to add a dropdown (child) under every generated parent row. The treeview will look like as follows:

```
list = [data1,data2,data3,data4]
-_________________-
data1
   dir1
   dir2
data2
   dir1
   dir2
data3
   dir1
   dir2
data4
   dir1
   dir2
```

I try to create unique variable names, however, when I generate them, they of course get overwritten when I define the treeview, and I get following error _tkinter.TclError: Item 1 already exists with tkinter treeview
My code for what I have tried:

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(self.home_frame)

        tree["columns"] = ("one", "two")
        tree.column("one", width=100)
        tree.column("two", width=100)
        tree.heading("one", text="coulmn A")
        tree.heading("two", text="column B")

        tree.insert("", 0, text="Line 1", values=("1A", "1b"))

        data = ['stocks','crypto','Forex','ETF','mutual funds']

        n=1
        for i in data:
            print(i)
            j = str(n)
            i+j = tree.insert("", n, "dir2", text=str('l'), values=("foo","bar"))

            tree.insert(i+j, "end", "dir 2", text="sub dir 2", values=("2A", "2B"))
            tree.insert(i+j, "end", "dir 3", text="sub dir 2", values=("2A", "2B"))
            n+=1
        tree.grid(row=2,column=0)
```

Comment: `i+j = tree.insert(...)` is not a valid statement in Python, so the posted code should not run.

Comment: yeh obviouslt it doesn't work, but it was my attempt at making unique ID's

Comment: What I said the code fails is due to syntax error, so the mentioned exception will not be raised.

Answer (score 0):

`Treeview.insert()` will create an unique `iid` for you if you do not specify the `iid` option.  So just use the unique `iid` returned by `.insert()`:

```py
for item in data:
    iid = tree.insert("", "end", text=item, values=("foo","bar"))
    tree.insert(iid, "end", text="sub dir 1", values=("2A", "2B"))
    tree.insert(iid, "end", text="sub dir 2", values=("2A", "2B"))
```